# Android: Downloading flickr images

Tags: java, android

I have a project that I'm having trouble with (for an internship). My assignment is to create an Android app that downloads a random image from Flickr after running a search for a specified tag.

I know Flickr has an API, and I have an api key, but I'm struggling with understanding how to integrate this into an app, as it seems examples in Java are a bit sparse. Does anyone know the process of using the API to download an image after running a search? (Or if there's an easier way to do it without the API/being authenticated, that works too).

I should also mention that I can't use any external libraries.

Comment: Are you allowed to use third-party libraries like the ones mentioned by Itai Hay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For searching public photos you don't need to authenticate yourself with Flickr service API. First you have to register an API key for your apps, call the correct API function from the list

http://www.flickr.com/services/api/

and parse the result in format of JSON. But you can't use 3rd library in your project, you can follow this post

http://hintdesk.com/android-show-images-from-flickr-with-imagegridview/

it uses only Android libraries.

Comment: What if we want only photostream images ?

Answer (score 1):

Well I can feel the difficulty of doing this w/o the so sweet and easy [Flickrj-Android](https://code.google.com/p/flickrj-android/) or [Flickr4Java](https://github.com/callmeal/Flickr4Java) :)

The method you need is [flickr.photos.getSizes](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.getSizes.html).

> Returns the available sizes for a photo. The calling user must have permission to view the photo.

You do not need to authenticate your API key if you do not want to download non-public photos.
Just get the wanted photo-id with a simple search ([flickr.photos.search](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html)) and download the wanted photo with a simple URL file stream.

The returned data has the wanted download URL. So just run a parser and download away.

Comment: What if we want only photostream images ?